# Error in importing module in AWS Lambda due a dependency

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am setting up a web scraper in python and would want it to run in Amazon Lambda

While using pycharm I imported "newspaper3k" package, which allows to extract text from url of news article.
The given code runs fine. Filename is "test.py"

While running in AWS Lambda I get the following error:
"{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'test'"
}"

Handler is "test.lambda_handler"

There is no error when I remove the "import newspaper". I have checked the deployment package and there is newspaper, so the command should run fine.

How to correct it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import newspaper   #error is here
def lambda_handler(event, context):
# TODO implement
   url = "https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/todays-paper/tp-opinion/Towards-equity-in-direct-taxes/article20050257.ece" 
   art = newspaper.Article(url)
   art.download()
   art.parse()
   print(art.text)
```

Comment: Are you sure? The error message implies that it can't import your code, `test.py`.

Comment: How did you create the deployment package? The newspaper library has dependencies like lxml and Pillow which use C libraries. If you've installed newspaper on your local machine and just zipped that, those C libraries can be incompatible with the Lambda environment. That might be the reason why you can't `import newspaper`.